# How do I migrate a Mercurial (Hg) source code repository to TFS?

Tags: tfs, mercurial, version-control-migration, tfs-migration

This seems to be the opposite of what most people are trying to do.  I want to export all of the changesets from a Mercurial (Hg) repository and import them into Team Foundation Server 2010 and include the history. I can't be the only one going *to* TFS, right? It looks like I might be able to export from Hg to Git and then Git to TFS.  Is there a better way?

Comment: I take it you also want to bring in the Repo History?

Comment: Not necessarily, it just helps to frame the question.

Comment: @NathanE Why is TFS a bad idea vs. Mercurial/Git?

Comment: @RobertBertstein: It's a matter of opinion. I've used both and Mercurial is light-years ahead of TFS's VCS when it comes to ease of use and "getting s**t done". TFS erects many roadblocks that can take hours or even days to get past. I put up with TFS with 4 years and as soon as I spent just a day with Mercurial I already felt huge improvements. It was like night and day.

Comment: @nbevans: TFS has come a long way since your comment. Hg doesn't seem to have a good way to relate to a bug tracker, but TFS does both and marries them well. Integrated VS support is excellent. My buddy thinks the build server suite is great. VS2013 marred a lot of the check-in UI, but there's a work around for it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can (for **bidirectional** data-exchange) use [SVNBridge](http://svnbridge.codeplex.com/)