# Tools to migrate from Mercurial to TFS

Tags: mercurial, tfs

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do I migrate a Mercurial (Hg) source code repository to TFS?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8567038/how-do-i-migrate-a-mercurial-hg-source-code-repository-to-tfs)

Is there a tool to migrate source code with history from Mercurial to [TFS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Team_Foundation_Server)?