# Migration of Mercuriel repo to TFS

Tags: tfs, mercurial, tfs-migration

Does anyone have some expirience with migration of **Mercuriel** repo to **TFS** source control using **TFS** Integration tools. What I need is the following

1. Migration of all source controlled items to **TFSC**
2. Migration of History

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I migrate a Mercurial (Hg) source code repository to TFS?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8567038/how-do-i-migrate-a-mercurial-hg-source-code-repository-to-tfs)