# Is it possible to migrate code from Bitbucket to TFS 2018.3 (On premise) with history?

Tags: tfs, bitbucket

We are trying to migrate the code from BitBucket to TFS (on-premise) 2018.3 and we are looking for a possible way to migrate the code with history.

We searched a lot and haven't found a way or tool for this process.

Are there any tools which help to create bidirectional sync between TFS and BitBucket?

Comment: If it's Git, [this might help](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20757043/migrate-git-to-tfs-with-all-history)

Comment: And [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8567038/how-do-i-migrate-a-mercurial-hg-source-code-repository-to-tfs) seems to cover Mercurical.

Comment: Do you want to stay in Git or move to TFVC?

Comment: We want to use TFVC

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Convert Git repository to TFVC version control](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48397169/convert-git-repository-to-tfvc-version-control)

Comment: You can use git-tfs for this. Don't use git-tf, it's no longer updated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to your description, seems you want to migrate code with git version control in bitbucket to TFVC version control.

In this case, we recommend you to try external tools like [**Git-TFS**](https://github.com/git-tfs/git-tfs) for importing.

git-tfs is a **two-way bridge** between TFS (Team Foundation Server) and git, similar to git-svn. It fetches TFS commits into a git repository, and lets you push your updates back to TFS.

Other things about the migration, you could take a look at our suggestions here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/learn/git/migrate-from-tfvc-to-git#advanced-migrations

Comment: Thank you for the information and we tried but we were unable to push the code to TFS
Here are things we tried,
1. We have code in Bitbucket cloud 
2. We have installed Vs2105 to support GIT-TFS plugin and GIT for windows on windows 2016 server
3. By using GIT for windows, we have cloned the code from Bitbucket to local folder (created a folder)
Command: git clone https://******/****.git
4. Now we are trying to push this code with history to TFS but getting error.
5. Could you please tell me the way/command to push/checkin the code (with history) to TFS

Comment: @Sam Which command are you using, could you post the detail error info. You could also file a new case to track this.